# How to find blood pressure from osciloscope image

Tags: continuous-signals

We have measured the human blood  pressure with the sphygmomanometer connected to relative senzor of the pressure and osciloscope. We measured the offset of the sensor as $U_{OFF}=1.01\ V$ and the sensitivity $k=0.02425\ \frac{V}{mmHg}$.

By measuring the pressure on the human's arm, we got this image:
[image]
How to find systolic and diastolic pressure in there?

We got formula for counting the pressure $p$ out of the output voltage $U_x$
$$p=\frac1k\cdot (U_x-U_{OFF})$$

I thought the highest value is the first vertical cursor, which shoud be  $9.6\ mV$ according to the table in the right top of the image, but if I count with this value and the formula above, I get the maximum pressure $-40\ mmHg$. We didn't get very clear instructions how to count systolic and diastolic preassure either. I only know, systolic pressure should be half of the maximum value.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Some questions: How did you connect the sensor to the oscilloscope? With AC or DC coupling? How did you measure the offset voltage? You say -40Pa but your formula is mmHg? Using p . k = (Ux - Off) I get Ux-Off should be about 2.91V for p = 120 mmHg. What is the blue line? 
Some comments:
The first cursor give volts to the '2' marker, not to the bottom of the signal, so the spike is about 15mV. Since the signal is either side of the '2', which I assume is 0V, then it might be AC coupled which in that case forget about Uoff.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote something stupid. The pressure would be $-40\ mmHg$. 

We used the sensor Honeywell 24PCCFA6G. I don't know what does coupling mean, but we set the lightblue canal to measure AC and the darkblue DC. We measured the offset with the darkblue signal, while the sphygmomanometer was without any pressure.

Comment: The coupling type is how the signal passes through into the measurement. If it is AC then any constant part - like the offset voltage Uoff - is filtered out, leaving only the dynamic part of the signal. This is the light blue graph in your picture. So you can set Uoff to 0V. However, with AC coupling (the light blue graph) instead of measuring absolute voltage (e.g. 9.6mV) you have to measure the peak to baseline voltage (about 14mV). This is because 0V is just the mean of the dynamic signal.

Comment: This is why the light blue graph starts moving upwards - the pulses are getting smaller. Still 15mV = 1psi for the sensor you are using = 51mmHg... Which might makes sense if the pulse represents the extra pressure from the pulse (systolic - diastolic?). I'm not sure how blood pressure works?